# Получение токена в вк

Tags: php, вконтакте

Когда пытаюсь получить токен функцией file_get_contents($url) появляется ошибка:
Warning: file_get_contents([https://api.vk.com/oauth/token?бла](https://api.vk.com/oauth/token?%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B0) бла бла): failed to open stream: Connection refused in бла бла бла
Чем может быть вызвано такое или что я не так делаю?

Comment: Какая версия PHP ?

Comment: Версия php - 5.5

Answer (score 1):

HTTPS поддерживается начиная с PHP 4.3.0. Кроме того, убедитесь, что сервер имеет действующий сертификат, брандмауэр разрешает исходящие соединения и allow_url_fopen в php.ini установлен в `On`. А также убедитесь что раширение `php_openssl` установлено и подключено. В php.ini  у вас должно быть следующее:

```
extension=php_openssl.dll

allow_url_fopen = On
```

Comment: "убедитесь, что сервер имеет действующий сертификат" -- сервер ВК-то? Наверняка. А инициатору соединения он не потребуется.

Comment: Все проверил, все включено

Answer (score 1):

В моем случае проблема решилась разрешением опции "HTTP(s) outgoing connections" в Firewall Options хостинга